# LINQ to XML select element from specific node/nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML file and would like to create objects based on the content of the file. The XML file looks like:

```
<DefaultView>
    <Module>
      <Variable Name="gTestInt1" Enable="True" />
      <Task Name="Task1">
        <Variable Name="testInt" Enable="True" />
        <Variable Name="testReal" Enable="True" />
        <Variable Name="testString" Enable="True" />
      </Task>
      <Task Name="Task2">
        <Variable Name="testInt1" Enable="True" />
        <Variable Name="testReal" Enable="True" />
        <Variable Name="testString" Enable="True" />
      </Task>
    </Module>
</DefaultView>
```

My LINQ statement is the following:

```
var globalVariables = (from cfg in _xElements.Descendants("Module").Descendants("Variable")
                      select new Variable
                      {
                          Name = cfg.Attribute("Name").Value,
                          Enable = bool.Parse(cfg.Attribute("Enable").Value)
                      }).ToList();
```

So my problem is that I get all the Variable objects that are in the XML file, including the the ones in the child nodes (Task).
But I just want the Variable objects that are not in any child node. Just the ones in the Module node.

How must my LINQ query look like to get this?

Comment: Look at the difference between XElement `Elements` and `Descendants`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Descendants` method returns all of the descendant elements. You need to use `Elements` instead. Try something like this:

```
var globalVariables = (from cfg in _xElements.Descendants("Module")
                                             .Elements("Variable")
                      select new Variable
                      {
                          Name = cfg.Attribute("Name").Value,
                          Enable = bool.Parse(cfg.Attribute("Enable").Value)
                      }).ToList();
```